# Reliability of Windows Azure Storage Logging

Tags: azure-storage

We are in the process of creating a piece of software to backup a storage account (blobs & tables, no queues) and while researching how to do this we came across the possibility storage logging. We would like to use this feature to do smart incremental backups after an initial full backup. However in the introductory post for this feature [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/08/02/windows-azure-storage-logging-using-logs-to-track-storage-requests/) the following caveat is mentioned:

> During normal operation all requests are logged; but it is important to note that  logging is provided on a best effort basis.  This means we do not guarantee that every message will be logged due to the fact that the log data is buffered in memory at the storage front-ends before being written out, and if a role is restarted then its buffer of logs would be lost.

As this is a backup solution this behavior makes the features unusable, we can't miss a file. However I wonder if this has changed in the meantime as Microsoft has built a number of features on top of it like blob function triggers and very recently their new Azure Event Grid.

My question is whether this behavior has changed in the meantime or are the logs still on a best effort basis and should we stick to our 'scanning' strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior for Azure Storage logs is still same. For your case, you might be better off using the EventGrid notification for Blob storage: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-event-grid-an-event-service-for-modern-applications/

Comment: Is that using some new eventing API or like WebJobs based on a scan followed by tracking the $logs container?

Comment: Yes it is a new event API supported by Azure Storage and Event Grid. It is reliable unlike the previous methods.